# Can I find $Im(T)$, $Ker(T)$ and $Im(T)$ $\cap$ $ker(T)$ with given $[T]_B$ and unknown basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $B = \{ v_1, v_2, v_3 \}$ basis of $R_3[x]$ vector space.
I do not know what are the vectors of B, but I do know that $[T]_B = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3\\ 
24 & 14 & 3\\ 
2 & 6 & 17
\end{pmatrix}$.

Now, is it possible to find $Im(T)$, $Ker(T)$ and $Im(T)$ $\cap$ $ker(T)$?

And if I was given that $B = [1, 1+x, 1+x+x^2]$ how would my answer change?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a linear map $T:\Bbb R_2[x]\to\Bbb R_2[x]$ and you know
that
$$
[T]_B= \left[\begin{array}{rrr} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 24 & 14 & 3 \\ 2 & 6 & 17
  \end{array}\right]
$$
where $B=\{1,1+x,1+x+x^2\}$. Knowing this matrix tells you *everything*
about $T$.

The dictionary between linear algebraic statements about the *map* $T$ and
the *matrix* $[T]_B$ is

- $\DeclareMathOperator{image}{image}\image(T)\leftrightarrow\DeclareMathOperator{Col}{Col}\Col({[T]_B})$
- $\ker(T)\leftrightarrow\DeclareMathOperator{Null}{Null}\Null([T]_B)$

The idea is that it's easier to work numerically with the matrix $[T]_B$ than the abstract map $T$.

Let's demonstrate this by finding a basis for $\image(T)$. A basis for the column space of $[T]_B$ can be computed by finding the reduced row-echelon form of $[T]_B$. In our case
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{rref}{rref}\rref [T]_B=
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]
$$
Since all three columns are pivot-columns, this tells us that all of the columns of $[T]_B$ form a basis for $\Col[T]_B$. Our dictionary then tells us that
\begin{align*}
1(1)+24(1+x)+2(1+x+x^2) &&
2(1)+14(1+z)+6(1+x+x^2) &&
3(1)+3(1+x)+17(1+x+x^2)
\end{align*}
form a basis for the image of $T$.

Can you find a basis for the kernel using this method (hint: it's quite easy in this case)?